# Unable to house iframe within div element - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, iframe, css-float

Whenever I attempt to render a youtube embed within a created div element, the video extends beyond the bounds of the div I created.

NOTE: This is a homework assignment. I'm not looking for code to copy, just a hint or nudge in the right direction.

-Rules cannot be placed within the HTML code, they must be in the style sheet

-The rules already set within the style sheet are outlined in the assignment (including float).

[Local render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4avp.png)

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #60c90e;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
}

.video {
   width: 95%;
   margin: 2.5%;
   border-radius: 20px;
   padding: 1%;
   background-color: white;
}

.footer {
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 50px;
}

.video iframe {
    width: 65%;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link href="CSS/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

  <div class="content">

    <div class="video">

        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vC130RwBJQ8" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <h3>test</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis. Orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id. Tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor </p>

   </div> <!-- end of video -->

 </div> <!-- end of content -->

<footer class="footer">test</footer>

</div> <!-- end of container -->   

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floated `iframe` inside the `.video` `div`. Without editing the HTML you can do that using the `::after` pseudo element. I've added the following code to your example above:

```css
.video::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Working snippet:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #60c90e;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
}

.video {
   width: 95%;
   margin: 2.5%;
   border-radius: 20px;
   padding: 1%;
   background-color: white;
}

.footer {
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 50px;
}

.video iframe {
    width: 65%;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.video::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">

  <div class="content">

    <div class="video">
        <iframe width="560" height="560" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vC130RwBJQ8" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <h3>test</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis. Orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id. Tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor </p>

   </div> <!-- end of video -->

 </div> <!-- end of content -->

<footer class="footer">test</footer>

</div>
```